# How can I get content of fields of a webpage and store them to the database in java

Tags: java

I have a link of HTML page, which have 4 fields first name,last name, age, sex. If I open that link into browser it will show the fileds and data also.

I want to get all these data according to field in Java.

Comment: And what is your specific question?

Comment: Please add proper details. What have you tried ? In which platform are you working? Else you will get negative votes.

Comment: What You Want? What's your Problem???

Comment: Look up "web scraping" on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). With this project you can analyze the structure of a Homepage and get the values of the HTML-Nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an HTML file use a `jsp` file for your form.
Submit your form to a `servlet`, let the `servlet` make the database connection and insert the provided values to the database.

Comment: he mentioned that he only has a link, no whole HTML-File where he can make edits